# How to set up DotNetNuke for development

Tags: dotnetnuke

I am part of a team of .NET developers and we're trying to use the DNN platform as a way to have a website template so that we will not have to spend weeks or months building core functionality, such as authentication, permissions, navigation, etc.  However, I'm very confused as to how the platform works as well as how it's installed.  I'v spent many hours researching online at http://www.dnnsoftware.com/ as well as other sites, which only added to my confusion.  Here are some specific questions which are still unanswered:

1. Do we install the source code or not?  http://www.dnnsoftware.com/wiki/how-to-install-the-source-package-of-dotnetnuke says that it's not recommended to install source code.  On the other hand, http://www.dnnsoftware.com/wiki/packages says that we should use the source code if we are developers (which we are).
2. If we don't use source code, how do we write code which will be used to add functionality, style, or business logic to our site?  Where exactly do we put this code?
3. I keep on seeing the term "module" being thrown around.  What in the world is a module??  Is it a separate .csproj file?  Is it a .cs file saved as part of the website?  If so, how would we incorporate it without the source code?
4. Like any other application, we need to be able to maintain full control of builds and deployments.  With this, we can see history of what we did, roll back changes if necessary, etc.  Currently, for our other projects, we build with TeamCity and deploy with OctopusDeploy.  Where does that fit into working with DNN without source?  I also know that DNN is set up as a web site project not a web application project (see here http://www.dnnsoftware.com/forums/threadid/338902/scope/posts/threadpage/1) and web site projects is a technology not really being maintained by the newer versions of Visual Studio, and may be harder to deploy as well.  Assuming I DON'T want to convert (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2009/10/29/converting-a-web-site-project-to-a-web-application-project.aspx), how would I build/deploy the web site project?
5. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2009/10/29/converting-a-web-site-project-to-a-web-application-project.aspx seems to state that it's not recommended to remove dependencies from DNN and replace them with other ones.  If that's really true, it makes the whole platform seem very fragile and makes me wonder if I'm using the wrong tool altogether.  Was DNN really meant for developers or not?  (And if not, what *was* then intended use?)

Answer (score 5):

Start here->

http://www.christoc.com/Tutorials/All-Tutorials/aid/1

1) Don't touch the DNN source, trust me, it isn't worth the headache

2) You add functionality, override style, etc, through the use of Extension (modules and skins)

3) A separate CSProj (check out my templates http://www.christoc.com/Tutorials/All-Tutorials/aid/2

4) You will deploy by taking the ZIP file from each extension and either uploading through the host/extension page, or taking the ZIp file and putting it into /install/module/ in the root of your deployment target, then have a process call /install/install.aspx?mode=installresources

5) DNN is for sure meant for developers, but it is a framework, build on the framework, don't go in and start jacking the framework itself.

Comment: I get you regarding leaving the source alone; problem is they're using an old version of Telerik.  We have a paid version which is much newer; we'd want to swap out the older references for the new ones.  Am I crazy?

Comment: I wouldn't recommend it. You can still use the newer telerik controls in your own development

Answer (score 2):

I would start by getting a DNN site running on your local. This is fairly straight forward for any .NET developer.

A module is an extension for the DNN framework that you can essentially (once correctly installed) drop on a DNN page (referred to as tab). All your business logic will go in your own modules and the code for these modules will be the only things that you will have to source control. Do not make core changes to DNN as they will be blown away if you ever upgrade.

You do not need to use Christoc's module template if your module will only need to be deployed once. I find that it brings in a lot of unnecessary components and references that you probably will not need. Create your module's using webUserControls that inherit from DotNetNuke.Entities.Modules.PortalModuleBase. Drop the .ascx file in its own folder under DNN's DesktopModules folder and all required .dll's in DNN's bin folder. In DNN, go to Host>Extensions and create a new extention. To the extension add a module control and add your ascx files as controls (leave your default view's key blank). Other views should have unique keys and you can navigate to them in DNN using EditUrl("KeyName").

Drop your module on a DNN page and go from there.

This is of course an over simplification but it should get you going. There are many tutorials online that I advise you watch to learn the basics like Globals.NavigateUrl() to navigate between tabs and how DNN is put together. This forum topic might assist you [http://www.dnnsoftware.com/answers/dnn-7-module-development-step-by-step-tutorial](http://Learning%20DNN%20Dev)

Comment: Where do I get DotNetNuke.Entities.Modules.PortalModuleBase from?

Comment: Reference the DotNetNuke.dll in your project. The .dll will be in DNN's bin folder

Comment: Typical usings (you will not need them all for a basic module)

using DotNetNuke.Entities.Modules;
using DotNetNuke.Services.Exceptions;
using DotNetNuke.UI.Skins;
using DotNetNuke.UI.Skins.Controls;
using DotNetNuke.Common.Utilities;
using DotNetNuke.Framework;
using DotNetNuke.Web.Client;
using DotNetNuke.Web.Client.ClientResourceManagement;

Comment: "Create your module's using webUserControls..." so I'm creating a blank class library for this?

Comment: Create a blank asp.net webforms website project (you will not need the web.config). Add references to DotNetNuke.dll, DotNetNuke.Web and DotNetNuke.Web.Client. Then add your WebUserControls that inherit from DotNetNuke.Entities.Modules.PortalModuleBase instead of System.web.webusercontrol (or whatever the base class is I forget). Try get a hello world working from there. I will try and get a blog post up about it if you are still battling but there is lots of info online that should get you on your way.

Comment: For anyone considering Octopus Deployment of DNN modules, I'd recommend DnnPackager (of which I am the creator) https://github.com/dazinator/DnnPackager and also this blog post discusses it: http://darrelltunnell.net/blog/2015/04/29/automating-dotnetnuke-deployments-with-octopus-deploy/